# Can I bring a smart door lock in flight, in hand carry or check-in bag?

Tags: indian-citizens

Can I bring a smart door lock in flight, in hand carry or check-in bag?

[image]

---

Inside it has a battery and weighs about 3 kg.

Comment: Where are you travelling from (and to)? How is the lock powered? What kind of battery is inside?

Comment: How big and how heavy is the lock (in packaging?

Comment: This is going to depend on the size of the battery inside the lock, as well as the restrictions that the specific airline you are flying with places on carrying batteries in luggage.   Without this information we cant really give you an answer.

Comment: The [TSA website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all) is reliable reference point on luggage restrictions

Comment: If the battery is removable then yes you can bring it but in other case you can simply put it in the check-in.

Comment: @Bilal, I doubt that is true, it does depend on other things like measurement and battery power.

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove the battery (most likely you can) then you can check it in or hand carry. If you cannot remove the battery, it’s a big depends.

If the lock is too big it may deems as a weapon and you cannot hand carry so maybe you have to check it in.